# What game did these black and yellow dice come from?

Tags: identify-this-game, dice

I found these in Australia: A set of six six-sided dice, black with yellow markings. The dice are identical. The sides are the numerals 1, 2, and 3; an unfilled pip and a filled pip; and a weird tentacle thing. (From different angles the tentacle thing looks like a witch's hat or a pitcher plant.) There's a certain gothic flair to the forms of the numerals: The "1" doesn't have a flat bottom, for example.

These are third-hand dice, so it's hard to say whether they're separated from other game pieces or somehow constitute an entire game on their own.

[image: Six dice with numerals 1, 2, 3; an unfilled pip and a filled pip; and a weird tentacle thing.]

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Well, *that* was an obscure one.

As seen in the below image, these dice are from the 2006-07 Collectable Miniatures game [Dreamblade](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/22897/dreamblade). As far as I can tell, the game was extremely popular in a very small niche, and without the miniatures themselves I don't think the dice have any particular intrinsic value. They look pretty neat, though.

[image: Some Dreamblade miniatures, and the dice in question]